# Hadoop MapReduce Out of Memory on Small Files

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I'm running a MapReduce job against about 3 million small files on Hadoop (I know, I know, but there's nothing we can do about it - it's the nature of our source system).

Our code is nothing special - it uses `CombineFileInputFormat` to wrap a bunch of these files together, then parses the file name to add it into the contents of the file, and spits out some results. Easy peasy.

So, we have about 3 million ~7kb files in `HDFS`. If we run our task against a small subset of these files (one folder, maybe 10,000 files), we get no trouble. If we run it against the full list of files, we get an out of memory error.

The error comes out on `STDOUT`:

```
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 15690"...
```

I'm assuming what's happening is this - whatever JVM is running the process that defines the input splits is getting totally overwhelmed trying to handle 3 million files, it's using too much memory, and `YARN` is killing it. I'm willing to be corrected on this theory.

So, what I need to know how to do is to increase the memory limit for `YARN` for the container that's calculating the input splits, not for the mappers or reducers. Then, I need to know how to make this take effect. (I've Googled pretty extensively on this, but with all the iterations of Hadoop over the years, it's hard to find a solution that works with the most recent versions...)

This is Hadoop 2.6.0, using the MapReduce API, YARN framework, on AWS Elastic MapReduce 4.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would spin up a new EMR cluster and throw a larger master instance at it to see if that is the issue.

```
--instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.4xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge
```

If the master is running out of memory when configuring the input splits you can modify the configuration 
[EMR Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/EmrConfigurations.html)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure where to increase the memory limit, though. Obviously, not for the reducers. But for the mappers? Are the input splits calculated in a mapper container? Or is there another part of the ecosystem where that job lives (based on the source code of `CombineFileInputFormat`, it seems to all be on thread, so I would think it's probably in some container on the master instance. I haven't found a setting for giving that access to more memory though... (It's on a c3.8xlarge instance w/ 60 gigs of RAM, so it should have quite a bit of headroom, but maybe not...)

Comment: The splits are calculated in the client application running in the master node. By default Hadoop gives the client 1G (HADOOP_HEAPSIZE) so this may need to be adjusted.  This can be adjusted via the hadoop-env property similar to examples at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. I'mago try this out and let you know what happens.

Comment: Increasing `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE` did the trick. The job executes in a matter of minutes, even on a small cluster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the MapReduce on 3 million individual files, you can merge them into manageable bigger files using any of the following approaches.
1. Create Hadoop Archive ( HAR) files from the small files.
2. Create sequence file for every 10K-20K files using MapReduce program.
3. Create a sequence file from your individual small files using forqlift tool.
4. Merge your small files into bigger files using Hadoop-Crush.

Once you have the bigger files ready, you can run the MapReduce on your whole data set.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. While I appreciate the help, these solutions are challenging for 2 reasons. 1) We need to preserve file names due to some long-standing issues with our data (I realize this doesn't rule out sequence files, for example, but it does rule out some things). 2) The master node was running out of memory trying to calculate the splits to hand all these files to, say, FileCrush or a sequence file mapper... (Though, hopefully ChristopherB's suggestion on heap size will help with this...)